# Android Studio Emulator Crashes on HP Chromebook

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I have an HP Chromebook and I've installed the Linux dependencies on it, git, Android Studio, etc. I have a program in Android Studio that works perfectly on a non-Chromebook Windows computer. However when running the default emulator-5554, the emulator opens and then instantly disappears with:

```
E/[minigbm:virtgpu.c(52)]: DRM_IOCTL_VIRTGPU_GET_PARAM failed with Invalid argument
E/[minigbm:virtgpu.c(52)]: DRM_IOCTL_VIRTGPU_GET_PARAM failed with Invalid argument
E/[minigbm:virtgpu_virgl.c(346)]: Skipping unsupported combination format:825382478
```

I've never seen this error before and search engine queries aren't producing results. If I run a Virtual Device made with AVD, nothing even launches (even if the specs are the exact same as what launches on another computer). Does anyone know what's happening and why the Android Studio emulator keeps crashing? Everything is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like not all Chrome books are created equal. Is your chrome book on this list?

Supported devices for the Android Emulator

- Acer: Chromebook 712 [C871]
- ASUS: Chromebook Flip C436FA
- Dell: Latitude 5300 2-in-1 Chromebook Enterprise, Latitude 5400 Chromebook Enterprise
- HP: Chromebook x360 14c
- Lenovo: Flex 5 Chromebook

More info https://chromeos.dev/en/android-environment#supported-devices-for-the-android-emulator

Comment: Yes, I have the "HP: Chromebook x360 14c" so it should work